# What do you mean by Microsoft Account, Tenant, Subscription?

Tags: azure

I started learning Microsoft Azure but I'm stuck 
Can anyone tell me what is the difference between Microsoft account vs tenant vs Subscription in detail?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "Microsoft account", this usually refers to personal Microsoft accounts (outlook.com/live.com/hotmail.com).
But it could also refer to organizational Azure Active Directory accounts.

They are both kinds of user accounts, both types can exist as members in an Azure Active Directory "tenant".
This tenant is basically an instance of Azure AD for your users, in your control.
When you log in to Azure, you are logging in to Azure AD.

An Azure subscription is where you deploy your services, create resources like databases etc.
A subscription is always linked to an Azure AD tenant.
The users in this linked tenant can be given roles in the subscription to access/modify resources.
If anyone wants access to the subscription, they need to be added to the Azure AD tenant first.
This can be done by creating them an account there, or by inviting them by their email as a "guest".

Answer (score 1):

microsoft account: the one used to log in

tenant: your azure active directory (usually the default is [account].onmicrosoft.com

subscription: your microsoft azure subscription, the one used to create services/ deploy your applications